# Why can't I declare multiple const in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**This is correct syntax:**

`let foo, bar;`

**This is incorrect**

`const foo, bar;`

Why is that?

And is there a way to declare a number of constants in one place, and define them in another? Apart from bound declaration & definition.

Comment: `const` in JavaScript is not like `final` in Java - the initialization has to be part of the declaration.

Comment: If there's some initialization to be done, you may want to do it in a separate function, perhaps defined in the same scope, and use its result as the `const` declaration's assignment. Also, there should be no need to pre-declare these at the top of a scope if that was the intent; declare them where you need them.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because a const declaration has to be initialized as well. This will work:

```
const foo = 1, bar = 2;
```

Answer (score 21):

A normal variable (declared with `var` or `let`) can be declared without a value, since you can assign to them later:

```
let foo;  // foo has value undefined
foo = 3;  // foo has value 3
```

However, you can't do the same with constants since you can't change their value after they have been declared:

```
const foo;  // ...?
foo = 3;    // this is not allowed because foo is constant
```

Therefore, you must declare and assign a value to a constant at the same time. This *can* be done with multiple consts at once:

```
const foo = 3,
      bar = 8; // this works fine, foo and bar are both constants
```

There's no way to declare a const in one spot and assign it in another. You must use `var` or `let` instead.

Answer (score 9):

As Sean Sobey said in his answer, this is because `const` values have to be declared with values.

I would add that you can declare multiple `const` values in one statement, e.g.

```
const [xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax] = [-2, 2, -1.5, 1.5];
```

It is useful to note (contrary to other answers here) that a `const` is not immutable. See:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149555/difference-between-immutable-and-const

For example:

```
const item = { price: 10 };
item.price= 15;
console.log(item.price);
```

This will output the updated price of 15.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but is a constant so you have to assign them a value in declaration

Answer (score 1):

`const` values cannot be changed after assigning. You are trying to declare it now to change its later, which is not going to work with `const`.
The solution of this problem is that you declare it with `let` or `var`.

Answer (score 1):

I would declare multiple variables like this:

```
const latCoordinate = 12, longCoordinate = 34
```

Or you could also do something like that if you have an Object in the first place:

```
const {latCoord, longCoord} = {latCoord: -0.12768, longCoord: 51.50354}
```

In that case, you can name variables the way you want like so:

```
const {latCoord: lat, longCoord: lng} = {latCoord: -0.12768, longCoord: 51.50354}
console.log(lat, lng) // => -0.12768, 51.50354
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` should be assigned a value when it's declared since it makes a read-only.

Comment: `const` **must** be assigned a value when it's declared, anything else is invalid JavaScript.